# Windows phone 7 Toast notification with app in foreground

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Quick question. 
I did this:

```
myChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(myChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);
```

So if I receive a toast notification while the application is in the foreground the myChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived function should be called. In that function I have:

```
void myChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived(object sender, NotificationEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
       ApplicationTitle.Text = "Toast Notification Message Received";
    });
}
```

The problem is that the function is never called and the ApplicationTitle is never changed.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Can you check if you actually receive a notification?

Comment: Is your channel registered to receive notifications?

Comment: If the application is not in the foreground the toast message appears on the top of the screen...so I think so..if I just leave the app and instruct my service to send a push it works. But not when it's on the foreground

Comment: Yes it is...in fact if the application is not in the foreground the toast notification works...but not when I have the application opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem...it seemed that the toast xml that was being sent was well enough formatted so the phone would receive it out of the app but not when it was inside it.
Wrote the xml by "hand" and didn't use xmlWriter and worked.

```
string toastMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
        "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
           "<wp:Toast>" +
              "<wp:Text1>" + title + "</wp:Text1>" +
              "<wp:Text2>" + message + "</wp:Text2>" +
           "</wp:Toast>" +
        "</wp:Notification>";
```